# Can a decorator modify a class before __init_subclass__ is called?

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-class

I'm using `__init_subclass__` in order to register subclass in a specific registry. The registry itself is another class that contain a dictionary to store those subclass. I wanted to create a decorator to link those two classes but I'm not sure it is possible as `__init_subclass__` is called before the decorator itself.

Here is a simple example that describe what I would like but that is not working for obvious reason:

```
class Registry:
     
     @classmethod
     def link(cls, other_class):
         other_class._regsitry = cls()
         return other_class

class Foo:
    
    _registry = None

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        if cls._registry = None:
            raise ...

        # Add the class to the registry
        ....


@Registry.link
class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

The thing here is that Bar will raise the exception as it does not have _registry. I understand why but I don't know if there is any possibility to do that with decorator ?

Comment: Why not remove `__init_subclass__` and move its logic into `Registry.link`?

Comment: Good question. I'm doing this as Registry contains a lot of method and attribute. As the Bar class will be define by the user I don't want to mess up with their class. They will need to subclass from Registry but they will inherit everything and it will increase the chance that they override a method or an attribute and break their code. Of course you can always document that but I thought of this solution of linking the class to avoid this situation

Comment: I don't understand why the decorator can't do the work alone.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. I thought you wanted me to put the `__init_subclasss__` in the Registry class and then subclass from it. I didn't see the .link... I think you might have solved my issue. Let me try i will come back to you. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MichaelButscher, I thought about doing what you said. I can't put all the logic in the Registry class as I won't be able then to register all the subclass of Bar ? The goal is that Bar and all it's subclass are registered to the Registry.